# How-To on implementing Page Object Model with Telerik Test Studio

Tags: telerik, pageobjects, telerik-test-studio

I am evaluating Telerik Test Studio (http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools) as a web regression tool and looking for a how-to on setting up and using of a Page Object Model environment like is possible in Selenium.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Their documentation is focused on record/playback which is very brittle, and my google searches haven't turned up relevant links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, you really need not implement a Page-Object model if you are using Telerik Test Studio(TTS). TTS comes with its own AUT Object manager which is of above average quality and does a decent enough job. However, if you must go for a Page-Object implementation; here are some guidelines:

1. You must install VS 2008 or upwards because you really don't want to do a lot of coding in the TTS standalone.
2. In the solution structure, add a class file for each of the pages that you are going to work with.
3. Implement the methods that you want to execute on the page elements as Public methods in the corresponding class.
4. Declare the properties of the pages as variables in the appropriate class.
5. In the Test class, instantiate the relevant page classes.

While it is true that there is no framework support as such for implementing the page-object model in TTS, the basic essence is easy to replicate. Beyond that, it is up to you to extend the approach to higher levels.